# Solving system of equation over distinct finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Is it possible to solve an equation systems which involves elements from distinct finite fields?
One example could be elements from $\mathrm{GF}(2)$ and $\mathrm{GF}(2^2)$:

**With:**
$x=[1,1,0,1]$ 
$y_1=A_1x$   in $\mathrm{GF}(2)$ 
$y_2=A_2x$   in $\mathrm{GF}(2^2)$

**How to solve:**
$[y_1,y_2] = [A_1,A_2]x$

Comment: Since $1\mid 2$, $GF(2)$ is a subfield of $GF(2^2)$ so you could just solve it in $GF(2^2)$. And then check that in the solution vector space, there is a vector where $y_1$ is in $GF(2)$.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer. But how to map the equations in $GF(2)$ to $GF(2^2)$?

Comment: They already are equations in $GF(2^2)$....